# why doesn't gradient descnet step back to avoid oscilation

Tags: optimization, gradient, gradient-descent

I am performing an optimization using gradient descent but sometime it jumps over the mimimum and the cost function increases. I added a condition that if cost function value increased then step back and make the learning rate smaller this time. It is working very well. Why is it that I am not seeing this in the literature anywhere? I have read a lot of optimization literature trying to adapt the learning rate but they never step back and modify their step. Is there something wrong with this approach?

Comment: I see it in the literature all the time. That is basically standard.

Comment: I have seen modifying the learning rate but they don't step back and modify their step

Comment: But you always do a line search and adjusting the step length is standard I think.